# Webapp and in-memory Node.js hashmaps

Tags: node.js, hashmap

I'm working on a webapp that has a lot of static content - like 20,000 records.
I'd like to create an in-memory hashmap that gets queried by a Node.js webapp upon an incoming URL.

Is this a bad practice? Is it faster than using a RDBMS like MySQL or MariaDB?

I'd simply grab the data from memory, change a template, and display back to the user. There's no user input of any sort.

I'm was worried about concurrency, but I don't think the Node.js event loop would allow for this anyhow.

Any thoughts on why this is a bad practice?

Comment: What about scaling? Running your application over multiple machines would cause them each to have individual (and probably different) hashmaps. Load balancing requests over such a setup would be impossible. Also, what happens when the application on 1 of the servers goes down? It would have to rebuild the hashmap again. A much better approach would be to have a NoSQL like redis for this.

Comment: This is a read-only JSON file that wouldn't change, ever.

Comment: And you're right, I could use a NoSQL DB, but I'd like to read the data from the database in-memory and query from it since I believe it'd be faster. But again, I'm not sure. What do you think?